# Does Python AppIndicator3 on KDE support labels?

Tags: kubuntu, python, kde, indicator

I've just moved from Ubuntu to Kubuntu and I have a small script written in Python that used to display a brief status indicator message (how long a service on our network has been up) on my screen using `appindicator`.

I'm revising the script for the KDE environment. It runs and I can see my icon but I can't get it to display the time next to the icon on my screen. My reading suggests that KDE does not support labels next to notification icons, but I can't find any definitive documentation on this subject. Specifically, I found some documentation somewhere (can't find it now) stating that under KDE, AppIndicator3 falls back to [KStatusNotifierItem](http://api.kde.org/4.10-api/kdelibs-apidocs/kdeui/html/classKStatusNotifierItem.html). That documentation makes no mention of labels.

But failing to find something in the docs is hardly a definitive answer to my question. So, like the subject says, does Python AppIndicator3 running under KDE support labels?

Comment: I agree that the docs on this stuff is awful. They should really improve them.

Comment: @ByteCommander & OP: I wonder if you know the answer to my question about `python-appindicator` https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273411/