# Is there a replacement for python-appindicator?

Tags: 20.04, python, indicator

`AppIndicator` allowed your app to create menus in GNOME, like this:

[image]

Specifically, with `python-appindicator`, you could do it in Python. However, it looks like `python-appindicator` is gone in the latest Linux distributions, including `Ubuntu 20.04`.

Is there a replacement for it? I couldn't find much.

BTW I wish the the same library worked with different desktops, like KDE and GNOME, but `AppIndicator` was GNOME-only, I believe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `python-appindicator` package is deprecated and GObject bindings are recommended. There are GObject bindings for appindicators and they should be used AFAIK.

There are two packages in ubuntu for python bindings for `appindicator`.
One is based on `libappindicator` and another is based on `libayatana-appindicator`
I donot know the core difference between the two but my guess is `ayatana-appindicator` is latest ones for clarity of names and are also available in other distros.

The package names are:

- `gir1.2-appindicator`
- `gir1.2-appindicator3`.
- `gir1.2-ayatanaappindicator`
- `gir1.2-ayatanaappindicator3`.

The `3` suffix one are for `gtk3` and can be used for gtk3 related apps.

[Here](https://github.com/sagarchalise/nepcalindicator/blob/master/nepcalindicator#L7) is my own use case which shows my native calendar in panel. Shown below is usage in gnome-shell with kappindicator extension along with dropbox.

[image: Using gnome-shell Kappindicator extension along with dropbox which also uses appindicator]

Basically, for documentation see https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/AyatanaAppIndicator3-0.1/index.html

P.S. The image is from fedora as I am currently in fedora desktop with gnome-shell 3.38.
I think ubuntu ships with https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator which can be used to show status tray and appindicators for already existing ones. I currently use it for `zoom`, `dropbox` etc

Comment: Are  the two packages souce-compatible with `python-appindicator`, or does your app need drastic changes to the code to use  them instead of `python-appindicator`?

Comment: You will require some tweaks to your codebase as far as I can tell. There are some information on this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators#Python_version . I think pygtk one is using python-appindicator. Also, https://askubuntu.com/questions/108035/writing-indicators-with-python-gir-and-gtk3 talks about writing indicators. But I have used gi.repository only so not sure how much change it will bring. As far as two package go, they seem to be compatible and have same API just the name differ AFAIK

Comment: @sagarchalise

Your comment helped me. Thanks! 

Answer (score 0):

There is a GObject introspection version of [`libappindicator`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/libappindicator) in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS repository. You have to find examples of its usage.

You have to try developing stuff on top of [`libayatana-appindicator`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/libayatana-appindicator) packages with python/gir bindings.

Also there is a MATE desktop environment which has support of many traditional indicators and appindicators on MATE Panel.

Comment: `libayatana-appindicator` seems to be 11+ years old, but it has only 4 stars on github. 0 examples in Python. It looks like abandonware at first glance...

Comment: Sounds really strange, last commit [was on 23 Jul](https://github.com/AyatanaIndicators/libayatana-appindicator/commits/master). It is absolutely alive.

Comment: @MWB: you were likely browsing an outdated mirror/fork. The official repository is really active, specially now since the original `libappindicator` from Ubuntu is deprecated. As for Python examples, `gir1.2-ayatanaappindicator3` is source-compatible with `gir1.2-appindicator3`, you just have to change the `from gi.repository import ...` line